# Servlets - Sharing Initialcontext among several Servlets

Tags: servlets, jdbc, datasource, jndi

I have my application logic divided into 3 servlets, two of them connecting to a database.

Both of them get database connections by:

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/AutoMedScan");
```

There problem here is that with each request, an new Context gets created. I could store the context in a `static final` variable but then I have one in each servlet (and so, code duplication).

What's the best way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's that big a problem.

But if you must do something about it, perhaps a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) that creates the context and stores it at application scope is the answer.